# Production-ready WebSocket IOT System - Software Design Advice

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, websocket, iot

I'm developing a system to control a range of IoT devices. Each set of devices is grouped into a "system" that monitors/controls a real-world process. For example system A may be managing process A and have:

- 3 cameras
- 1 accelerometer
- 1 magnetometer
- 5 thermocouples

The webserver maintains socket connections to each device. Users can connect (via a UI - again with WebSockets) to the webserver and receive updates about systems to which they are subscribed.

When a user wants to begin process A, they should press a 'start' button on the interface. This will start up the cameras, accelerometer, magnetometer, and thermocouples. These will begin sending data to the server. It also triggers the server to set the recording mode to true for each device, which means the server will write output to a database. My question:

Should I send a single 'start' request from javascript code in my UI to the server, and allow the server to start each device individually (how do I then handle an error, for example, if a single sensor isn't working - what about if two sensors don't work?). Or do I send individual requests from the UI to the server for each device, i.e. start camera 1, start camera 2, start accelerometer, start recording camera1, etc. and handle each success/error state individually?

My preference throughout the system so far has been the latter approach - one request, one response; with an HTTP error code. However, programming becomes more complex when there are many devices to control, for example - System B has 12 thermocouples.

Some components of the system are not vital - e.g. if 1 camera fails we can continue, however, if the accelerometer fails the whole system cannot run and so human monitoring is required. If the server started the devices individually from a single 'start' message, should I return an array of errors, or should the server know which components are vital and return a single error if a vital component fails? And in a failure state, should the server then handle stopping each sensor and returning to the original state - and what if that then fails? I foresee this code becoming quite complex with this approach.

I've been going back and forth over the best way to approach this for months, but I can't find much advice online around building complex, production-ready IoT systems for the real world. If anybody has any advice or could point me towards any papers/books/etc. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: server have to know which devices belong to group/system and have to manage whole group/system - system should work regardless of connected client(UI) which is not vital component. server should know which component is vital and stop whole group/system in case vital component has failures. so UI will receive summary health status of group/system ( "green", "orange", "red" )  along with statuses of individual devices/components (because UI is subscribed to group) and group/system will work ok regardless of connection status of UI observer. BTW, I think this question is off-topic - is too broad

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny thanks for your response. The UI is a vital component in a way - the system must only start when told to start by a human and must be paused the rest of the time. The UI acts as a control panel for system operators rather than just being a reporting dashboard. I guess the specific question was “should the server determine which devices to start when the ‘start’ message is received, or should the UI start each device explicitly”

Comment: should the absence(disconnect) of GUI stop the process? - no. You can send single web API request to start process (either through UI or from cron tab script) - it does not matter who initiated process. And process will not stop if UI observer drops out. server should observe drop outs(or failures) of vital components and halt process without participation of UI. For this to work server should start, monitor and manage individual components.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny The question is less about how to handle loss of UI during the process (this is fine and currently allowed) - it can just reconnect. The question is more about actually starting the devices at the beginning of the process - should the front-end JS send messages to the server to start each device individually with success/error responses for each, or should the front end send a single message that then triggers the server to send messages to each device to start them. And if there are device errors in that case how should the server notify the front end (an array of errors?)

Comment: server manages group/system/process. it means that UI sends single command to initiate process. and server pushes notifications about status of the process (asynchronously) - either by sending small chunks (overall group/system/process status + individual status messages per component) or single aggregate object, containing summary status and and array of statuses for relevant components - it is up to you to decide.